# How do I simulate a magnetometer and get an attitude?

Tags: attitude, attitude-determination-and-control, magnetic-field, sensors

I consider that I have a single magnetometer (i don't know if I need more), how can I model that sensor? This was my idea:

Consider a random unit length vector $\textbf{m}$ which is the magnetic field vector. Consider the attitude matrix $R$. Consider the inertial unit length body magnetic vector $\textbf{m}_b=R\textbf{m}$. How do I find $R$ from a single measurement? What I attempted to do was to project $\textbf{m}_b$ and $\textbf{m}$ unto to x,y,z unit vectors so I had three vectors in body frame and three vectors in the inertial frame and then use TRIAD to get the attitude matrix. This did not work.

I believe I must use three unit length measurement vectors but I don't know how to do it because I know the TRIAD in the context of two different star vectors (use cross product to get the third vector) but there exists only one magnet field vector? What should I do?

Comment: AFAIK, You need at least two vectors for the triad algorithm to work (third vector can be constructed from the cross product). What other sensors do you have other than the single magnetometer ?

Comment: Let us say I have two magnetometers. This second magnetometer is placed on the satellite and rotated 90 deg around an axis. Now let us make it align with the body frame because everything has to be in the same frame before processing. 
However now it is the same measurement as the other magnetometer because the two vectors would almost align if we account for noise. So i don't see how magnetometers can be used even with three of them. Its all the same vector.  I do understand your point regarding having a magnetometer and a sun sensor for example. I am interested in the magnetomter case.

Comment: @AJN I guess my question is how do I model a triaxial Magnetometer? But I think I will just use a body vector from the sun and a body vector from sun and then use TRIAD.

Comment: The model of a triaxial magnetometer is what you have already given in the question; $R\vec{m}=\vec{m}_b$. Attitude determination is a separate activity. For that you need one more vector (e.g. sun vector).